# Websphere 7/Data Sources: ORA-01017: invalid username/password;

Tags: oracle, websphere

I am setting up multiple datasources on WS 7 for JNDI access.

After clicking one of the datasources -> `Connection Pool Properties` -> `Connection Pool Custom Properties`, I gave two properties:

```
Property1 Name: user
value: someuser

Property2 Name: password
value: somepassword
```

And after save the configuration and get back to that data source, I hit the `Test connection` button so it give me a nice exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied DSRA0010E: SQL State = 72000, Error Code = 1,017
```

And I do see that exception from JVM log as well. The issue remains even get the server restarted?

What's going wrong then?

### Update 1

Forget to mention that I have set JAAS authentication to none but still get the exceptions..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try using an 'J2C authentication alias' to define your username/password pair instead of custom properties. You may see the link for J2C Authentication Alias definitions at right hand side of datasource definition screen. After you define you username/password pair as an authentication alias, you shall select that alias for your datasource form the list of aliases.

For reference you may check [Configuring a data source using the administrative console](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/tdat_ccrtpds.html) (item 10) at infocenter.

Comment: Thank you kurtcebe I have updated my question, actually I have removed the JAAS alias from current data source but still get that exception, ever after restart the server. But that link refer to very helpful information. Thanks again.